# Questions about ray class groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic number field (so there are no real embeddings) with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ . Let $w$ be the number of units in $K$ and $h$ be the class number of $K$. Let $\mathfrak{f}$ be a non-zero integral ideal in $K$, and let $\mathcal{I}_{\mathfrak{f}}$ be the ray class group mod $\mathfrak{f}$, i.e.
$$
\mathcal{I}_{\mathfrak{f}} = \frac{J_{\mathfrak{f}}}{P_{\mathfrak{f}}},
$$
where $J_{\mathfrak{f}}$ is the group of fractional ideals coprime to $\mathfrak{f}$ and, for imaginary quadratic fields, $P_{\mathfrak{f}}$ is the group of principal fractional ideals $(\alpha)$ with $\alpha \equiv 1 \mod{\mathfrak{f}}$. Let $h(\mathfrak{f})$ denote the order of $\mathcal{I}_{\mathfrak{f}}$, $\varphi(\mathfrak{f})$ the order of the multiplicative group $(\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{f})^*$, and $g$ the number of units $\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon \equiv 1 \mod{\mathfrak{f}}$. I have two questions pertaining to some literature I have read recently (namely [this paper of Coleman](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-61.3.433) and [this paper by Khale et. al.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2021.04.004))

1. In both papers linked above, there appears the term "ideal class group mod $\mathfrak{f}$." Is this meant to be the *ray* class group mod $\mathfrak{f}$, or is there some other object this term is referring to? From both papers, it seems the answer is yes, it's the ray class group, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something.
2. In the first paper linked above, there appears implicit in the arguments the identity
   $$
   h(\mathfrak{f}) = \frac{h\varphi(\mathfrak{f})g}{w},
   $$
   This appears specifically between displays (4.4) and (4.6). I would like a reference and/or an explanation of why this identity holds.

My algebraic number theory is not the strongest, and my familiarity with the literature and common jargon is low, so forgive me if these are "dumb" questions.

Comment: For those that find this post later, another proof of the identity for $h(\mathfrak{f})$ above is given in Proposition 2.1 of Chapter 3 of "Class Field Theory" by Nancy Childress.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1.** Surely, by "class group modulo $\mathfrak{f}$", the authors mean "ray class group modulo $\mathfrak{f}$". I guess the authors omit "ray", because $K$ has no real embedding, so there are no "rays" here.

**2.** Let $K^\times_\mathfrak{f}$ be the multiplicative group of elements $\alpha\in K^\times$ congruent to $1$ modulo $\mathfrak{f}$, so that $P_\mathfrak{f}$ is the multiplicative group of fractional ideals generated by such elements. Analogously, let $K^\times_{\ast,\mathfrak{f}}$ be the multiplicative group of elements $\alpha\in K^\times$ coprime to $\mathfrak{f}$, and let $P_{\ast,\mathfrak{f}}$ be the multiplicative group of fractional ideals generated by such elements. Then we have the following exact sequence of finite abelian groups, with the obvious homomorphisms:
$$1\to U/U_\mathfrak{f}\to K^\times_{\ast,\mathfrak{f}}/K^\times_\mathfrak{f}\to J_\mathfrak{f}/P_\mathfrak{f}\to J_\mathfrak{f}/P_{\ast,\mathfrak{f}}\to 1.$$
Indeed, the image of the second map and the kernel of the third map are equal to $UK^\times_\mathfrak{f}/K^\times_\mathfrak{f}$, while the image of the third map and the kernel of the fourth map are equal to $P_{\ast,\mathfrak{f}}/P_\mathfrak{f}$. Comparing the sizes of the groups in the exact sequence, we get that
$$|U/U_\mathfrak{f}|\cdot|J_\mathfrak{f}/P_\mathfrak{f}|=|K^\times_{\ast,\mathfrak{f}}/K^\times_\mathfrak{f}|\cdot|J_\mathfrak{f}/P_{\ast,\mathfrak{f}}|.$$
On the other hand, it follows from weak approximation that $J_\mathfrak{f}/P_{\ast,\mathfrak{f}}$ is isomorphic to the class group of $K$, hence our equation becomes
$$(w/g)\cdot h(\mathfrak{f})=\varphi(\mathfrak{f})\cdot h.$$

Comment: Apologies for the late follow-up question, but, can it be shown that the exact sequence splits? It seems to me (via naive arguments using the idelic formulation of class field theory, and the projection $\mathrm{Gal}(K(\mathfrak{f})/ K)\rightarrow\mathrm{Gal}(K(1)/K)$), that in fact something stronger is true: at least in the case where the unit group is of rank 0, we should have $\mathrm{Cl}_{\mathfrak{f}}(K) \simeq \mathrm{Cl}(K) \times (O_K/\mathfrak{f})^\times/W$, where $W$ denotes the roots of unity. However, I havent seen this result formally written anywhere, so I assume I am wrong.

Comment: @pedroelpanda Let me quote from Ch.4 of Cohen - Advanced Topics in Computational Number Theory (GTM 193): "To compute the ray class group $Cl_\mathfrak{m}(K)$ from this exact sequence, there are three problems that a priori may seem difficult. First, the exact sequence may not split. Hence, although it may be easy to compute the cardinality $h_\mathfrak{m}$ of $Cl_\mathfrak{m}(K)$, it may not be easy to compute its structure."

Comment: Thank you very much. If I may abuse your kindness a little more, do you know of any positive results on splitting for special cases (I care in particular about imaginary quadratic fields, where I imagine one might be able to prove something using explicit CFT via CM elliptic curves)? All I have found is this paper with specific results about (some) ray class fields of cyclotomic fields and real quadratic fields: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=24a960fc356f23b09339fda6aa41cf1320d075b6

Comment: @pedroelpanda Please open a new post for this question (on this site).